# Python file handling / re-writing a block of text from one .txt to another .txt

Tags: python, file-handling

I need to run a search of a block of text and once if finds a specific word - it will copy the whole paragraph into another .txt.

I have written enough code to find the word and copy the first line. Can anyone help me expand it to capture the whole paragraph?

```
with open(primary_text) as openfile:

    for line in openfile:

        if word in line.strip():

            print(line)
```

Edit:
Just to add, this doesn't write to the new file yet. I was just trying to capture the data first. The paragraph always ends with a blank line.

[primary_text] has the file path stored as a vairable earlier

[word] is a variable defined eariler from user input.

Comment: So your question is _specifically_ about finding a block of text from a file, right? Because there are other parts of the title and the body that makes this look like 3 different questions in one, like the part about writing the block of text. It's kind of unclear which _specific_ issue to solve.

Comment: Hi, yes I expanded the question. The ultimate task is to write to a new file. At the moment I'm just trying to capture and print the text. If someone can help me find and print to a file - that is great. I'd be happy if I could just capture the text at the moment.

Comment: Please provide sample input file and the block of text that must be matched. Is there a strict pattern to match? Or is it just as long word is in the line...?

Comment: Then re-focus your question on _just_ the part about capturing the text. Writing to a file is a separate problem that already has tons of similar posts here on SO. The problem, as I read it, is mainly about capturing the text.

Comment: It would be something like;


[word] this is the body of the text. this is the body of the text. this is the body of the text. this is the body of the text. this is the body of the text. this is the body of the text. this is the body of the text. this is the body of the text. this is the body of the text. this is the body of the text. 
[/n]

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm running before I can jump. I'll focus on the capturing the text first. Apologies, this is my first question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generator that returns paragraphs from a file instead of just lines:

```
def paragraphs(fp):
    para = ''

    for line in fp:
        if not line.strip():  # empty line
            if para:
                yield para
            para = ''
        else:
            para += line

    if para:
        yield para
```

and use it in your main program like this:

```
with open(...) as fp:
   for para in paragraphs(fp):
       if search in para: 
            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this way

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as read, open("file1.txt", "w+") as write:
    splitter = "\n\n"
    write.write(
        splitter.join(
            filter(
                lambda x: 'word' in x,  # replace 'word' with word you want to search in each paragraph
                read.read().split(splitter)
            )
        )
    )
```